# Is it possible to push public CocoaPod that has private CocoaPod dependency?

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods

I'm trying to

"pod trunk push MyPublicCocoaPod.podspec" to https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git

which has dependency of "s.dependency 'MyPrivateCocoaPod'" (requires below url to install, my-private-specs.git)

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

source 'https://github.com/my-private-specs.git'

Is there a way to release MyPublicCocoaPod in this kind of dependency structure?

I am getting below error:

- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `MyPrivateCocoaPod` depended upon by `MyPublicCocoaPod`

Does public CocoaPod need to be dependent of other public CocoaPods only in order to release? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public pods must be buildable publicly, so pods with private dependencies cannot be published to trunk.

You can publish to a private Specs repo. Details [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html).

Comment: thank for your response
What if my public repo uses as dependency a forked version of a Framework ? (in my Podfile I can specify the git repo and the branch, but not in my podspec)

Comment: In order to publish to trunk, all dependencies must all have corresponding publicly pushed podspecs.